# Symfony 3 : how to reordering an array collection with route action?

Tags: symfony, sorting, symfony-3.2, arraycollection

I have a `Product` Entity. Each product can have 0 or N pictures.
I have a `ProductPhoto` Entity which has a `order` property (0 = first).

On a page, I list all the pictures of my current product. I would like to manage pictures order with 2 up/down arrows.

When the user clicks on an arrow, it moves up/down the picture compared to the others.

[image]

So, on each arrow, there is a link that corresponds to a route action in my `ProductController`.

It's not very complicated to update only the order of the picture that moved, but I don't know how to update the order of other pictures in the ArrayCollection...

```
/**
 * Manage picture order
 *
 * @Route("/products/{id}/photos/{idphoto}/move-{direction}", name="prod_move_photo")
 */
public function movePhotoAction($id, $idphoto, $direction, Request $request) {
    $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $photo  = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ProductPhoto')->find($idphoto);

    if ($direction == 'up') {
        $order = $photo->getOrder() - 1;

        if ($order >= 0)
            $photo->setOrder($order);
        else
            $photo->setOrder(0);

    } elseif ($direction == 'down') {
        $order = $photo->getOrder() + 1;
        $photo->setOrder($order);

    } else {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException("The type of ordering '" . $direction . "' doesn't exist.");
    }

    $em->flush();

    // redirection
    return $this->redirectToRoute('prod_photos', array('id' => $id));
}
```

Maybe using PHP `uksort()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to update `order` fields in two `ProductPhoto`s moved by each other, right? So please try this:

```
/**
 * Manage picture order
 *
 * @Route("/products/{id}/photos/{idphoto}/move-{direction}", name="prod_move_photo")
 */
public function movePhotoAction($id, $idphoto, $direction, Request $request) {
    $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $photo  = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ProductPhoto')->find($idphoto);

    $order = $photo->getOrder();

    switch($direction) {

        case 'up':
            $newOrder = ($order >= 1) ? ($order - 1) : (int) 0;
            break;

        case 'down':
            $newOrder = $order + 1;
            break;

        default:                
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("The type of ordering '" . $direction . "' doesn't exist.");
    }

    $anotherPhoto = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ProductPhoto')->findOneByOrder($newOrder);

    $photo->setOrder($newOrder);
    $anotherPhoto->setOrder($order);

    $em->flush();

    // redirection
    return $this->redirectToRoute('prod_photos', array('id' => $id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but in the meantime, I found a solution that supports N pictures while yours support only 2. ;-) I will post it.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe I don't understand your question, but when u click an up/down arrow u need to reorder just two pics =)

Comment: Yes you're completely right, I didn't think about it ! Your solution works perfectly, thank you ! It's simplier than mine.

Comment: Can you edit your post just for 2 lines, you forgot a `$` when you update the order of `$anotherPhoto` (`++$order` and `--$order`)

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry.. Edited )

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Snegirekk works very well (and I use it), but here is the solution I found, if it can help...

```
/**
 * Manage picture order
 *
 * @Route("/products/{id}/photos/{idphoto}/move-{direction}", name="prod_move_photo")
 */
public function movePhotoAction($id, $idphoto, $direction, Request $request) {
    $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $photo  = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ProductPhoto')->find($idphoto);

    // Current order of the photo
    $currentPos = $photo->getOrder();

    // Determine new order
    if ($direction == 'up') {
        $newPos = ($currentPos > 0) ? $currentPos - 1 : 0;

    } elseif ($direction == 'down') {
        $newPos = $currentPos + 1;

    } else {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException("The type of ordering '" . $direction . "' doesn't exist.");
    }

    $product = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find($id);

    // Get product photos with actual order (moveElement() needs an array)
    $photos = $product->getPhotos()->toArray();

    // Reorder photos in ArrayCollection
    $this->moveElement($photos, $currentPos, $newPos);

    // Reorder photos in database (with keys of formatted ArrayCollection)
    foreach ($photos as $order => $p) {
        $p->setOrder($order);
    }

    $em->flush();

    // redirection
    return $this->redirectToRoute('prod_photos', array('id' => $id));
}

/**
 * Move an array element to a new index
 *
 * @param  array    $array      Array of elements to sort
 * @param  integer  $currentPos Current position of the element to move
 * @param  integer  $newPos     New position of the element to move
 * @return void
 */
public function moveElement(&$array, $currentPos, $newPos) {
    $out = array_splice($array, $currentPos, 1);
    array_splice($array, $newPos, 0, $out);
}
```